# React Router - get URL params outside of page component (inside of layout footer)

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm writing an app using React and trying to make a dynamic footer - I have a URL there that varies between pages

Is there any way to get URL params outside of page component somehow without copying footer to each page?

Comment: Please show us an [MVCE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and what you have tried that didn't work.

Comment: you can pass it as props to the footer possibly. If you provide a mvce as stated above we might be able to check it out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you using React Router? React Router v4+ contains a url query param.

```
const params = new URLSearchParams(this.props.location.search);
const foo = params.get('foo'); // bar
```

You can alternatively use `window.location.hash`